# После установки application icon, жалуется на QMainWindow

Tags: qt

После добавления в CMakeLists.txt

`if (WIN32)`

`set(app_icon_resource_windows "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/icons/programIcon.rc") qt_add_executable(programIcon main.cpp ${app_icon_resource_windows})`

`endif()`

Компилятор жалуется на `#include <QMainWindow>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите сообщение об ошибке полностью (текстовый вывод компилятора).

Comment: fatal error: QMainWindow: No such file or directory